# Inherit menu odoo 9 and add new item in custom module

Tags: inheritance, odoo, odoo-9

Is it possible inherit menu from web module and add new < li > item in custom module.

```
<t t-name="UserMenu">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <img class="oe_topbar_avatar" t-att-data-default-src="_s + '/web/static/src/img/user_menu_avatar.png'"/>
                <span class="oe_topbar_name"/> <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#" data-menu="documentation">Documentation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-menu="support">Support</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-menu="about">About</a></li>
                <li class="divider"/>
                <li><a href="#" data-menu="settings">Preferences</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-menu="account">My Odoo.com account</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-menu="logout">Log out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

</t>
```

Menu location is addons/web/static/src/xml/base.xml

I'm try with below example but what put in xpath and how find ID?

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend" name="static_resources_menu assets" inherit_id="?????">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">



            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To inherit template Please create a staic/src/xml/test.xml file

in test.xml file add

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <templates id='template' xmlspace='preserve'>

  <!--Extends UserMenu -->
   <t t-extend="UserMenu">

     <t t-jquery="li.divider" t-operation="after">
       <li><a href="#" data-menu="test">Test</a></li>
     </t>
   </t>

</templates>
```

Comment: @Vishno Loyal Hello, New item is not visible after add test.xml. Any additionl code in __openerp__,py or inherit in .py file?

Comment: yes in __openerp__.py add :-                                                                     'qweb':['staic/src/xml/test.xml'],